# Unable to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS on oracle virtual machine

Tags: 20.04, oracle

If I want to install ubuntu on oracle vm I can follow the installation until I get to the "Who are you" window. Unfortunately, I cannot enter anything there in the corresponding fields.
Does anyone have any idea what that could be?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you click into the box to capture your mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the box and my mouse got captured.

Comment: Did you try to restart the setup?

Comment: Yes, I restarted it several times.

Comment: Do you have keyboard imput enabled in the virtual machine

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, this is going to take some intense research! I will get back to you soon!

Comment: After some googling I found a possibly helpful article! :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039177/keyboard-not-working-in-oracle-vm-virtual-box